# C (Linux) - valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) after realloc

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

After running valgrind on my program I got following output:

```
==17731== Thread 2:
==17731== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17731==    at 0x401CD8: poll_existing_connections (connmgr.c:112)
==17731==    by 0x401ACD: connmgr_listen (connmgr.c:69)
==17731==    by 0x40161A: connmgr (main.c:148)
==17731==    by 0x5545609: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.22.so)
==17731==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==17731==    at 0x4C2AB8B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==17731==    by 0x401B64: poll_new_connection (connmgr.c:85)
==17731==    by 0x401AB9: connmgr_listen (connmgr.c:68)
==17731==    by 0x40161A: connmgr (main.c:148)
==17731==    by 0x5545609: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.22.so)
==17731==
```

I supsected something was wrong with the way I use realloc. I started googling and tried some solutions I found that worked for other users but neither of those solutions worked for me. 
I also tried using a different way (malloc new memory and copy the old values of the array in the new one) but that resulted in the same kind of error by valgrind.

Any suggestions on what might go wrong?

My code (connmgr.c:112):

```
sensor_conn_t * sensor_conn = dpl_get_element_at_index(sensor_sockets, i);
poll_action = poll_list[i].revents == POLLIN;
if(poll_action == POLLIN) { 
    //The sensor sent some data
    read_data(sensor_conn, i, buffer);
} else { 
    //No data received from the sensor
    check_timeout();
}
```

My code (connmgr.c:85):

```
//Add the new connection to an array so that it is pollable
struct pollfd * new_poll_list = realloc(poll_list, (nb_connections + 1) * sizeof(struct pollfd));
assert(new_poll_list != NULL);
poll_list = new_poll_list;

tcp_get_sd(client, &poll_list[nb_connections].fd);
poll_list[nb_connections].events = POLLIN;
```

Comment: You made `poll_list` larger but, where do you initialize the new element? Where is `poll_list[i].revents` initialized?

Comment: @Schwern I taught I initialized everything with these lines: tcp_get_sd(client, &poll_list[nb_connections].fd);
poll_list[nb_connections].events = POLLIN; 

Turns out I forgot to initialize poll_list[i].revents
Thanks a lot, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling realloc, but you are not initializing the contents of the buffer that are larger than the original buffer. Basically, all the memory that you have grown new_poll_list into is uninitialized.

After you call realloc, make sure to initialize the region that comes after the size of the original buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I taught that I initialized it with these tzo lines:
tcp_get_sd(client, &poll_list[nb_connections].fd);
poll_list[nb_connections].events = POLLIN;

apparently I am doing something wrong. How do you suggest I initialize them? (I am kind of a newbie to C)

Comment: @Jonas Explicitly set each element of the poll_list[nb_connections] struct to a value after the assertion.

Comment: As you and @Schwern suggested I didn't initialize everything (forgot the poll_list[i].revent).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are initializing a field:

```
poll_list[nb_connections].events = POLLIN;
```

Here you are testing the contents of a field:

```
poll_action = poll_list[i].revents == POLLIN;
  if(poll_action == POLLIN)
```

All very good, but they are *not the same field*.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem